# How to make a Chrome incognito shortcut in Windows work after Chrome updates

Tags: windows, windows-xp, google-chrome, shortcuts, private-browsing

I have created a shortcut to the Google Chrome application on Windows XP. I have modified the target line in the shortcut such that it ends in the argument to start Chrome in incognito mode.

The modification is as such for the `Target`: `"C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito`

[image: Google Chrome Properties]

The works until seemly Chrome updates and then I need to redo the above modification appending `--incognito`, again to the `Target:` line.

Is there a way to make this change more permanent, so that I can just do this one time and have a constant shortcut that's not going to randomly change back to a normal mode Chrome shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably either chrome or some other software is messing with the shortcut.

**Options:**

- Try naming the shortcut differently than the Default name.
- Create shortcut manually i.e. by right clicking on the desktop and select `New>Shortcut`and follow on screen instructions.

**Update Proof method:**
 Alternatively you can use **Batch file** to launch chrome in Incognito mode. (This will not be affected by updates or anything like that)
   Create a text file, paste following command to it, save it with
   extension **.bat**.

```
    C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito
    EXIT
```

Double Click the file to launch chrome. (You can customize the icon to make it look like the chrome shortcut)

Comment: In the process of trying the first part, a new alias with a different name.

Comment: @MrDaniel that's great, I hope you will also report results when done.

Comment: Renaming / creating the shortcut with a different name worked. I called it "Chrome Incognito"

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

- Open notepad copy/paste this code:

  ```
  @echo off
  cls
  start %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --incognito
  exit
  ```
- But if you want to let it open a website in incognito window it should be like this:

  ```
  @echo off
  cls
  start %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --incognito "http://www.example.domain"
  exit
  ```

  Replace 'example' with your website address, And also 'domain' with your website's domain, Like '.com' '.org' '.tk'...
- Save it as "Incognito".bat, replace with "Your File Name".bat.

Comment: The Chrome executable is NOT in the user profile directory

Answer (score 2):

i find this better as solution.

```
@echo off

start /d "c:\Program files\Google Chrome" Chrome.exe --incognito http://www.example.domain
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be that chrome overwrites this particular link. The simplest solution would be to make another link (somewhere else, or with a different name) with your modification, that chrome wouldn't overwrite automatically every times it gets updated.

Comment: As in right clicking and creating a new shortcut with the shortcut wizard. More details would be appreciated.

Comment: As in copy-pasting your shortcut (presumably in the same folder), renaming it "Chrome incognito", and then modifying the "target" the way you do with the normal shortcut (adding the `--incognito` parameter).