# Windows cannot find C:\Program...?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to open gmail in incognito and enter my credentials automatically when the pc starts up. Based on [this post](https://superuser.com/a/596287/232563) I have the following:

```
@echo off
cls
start %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --incognito "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier"
exit
```

However, when I double-click the `.bat` file, a cmd window appears with an error window in front that says:

> Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'. Make sure you typed it correctly, and then try again.

I think cmd is evaluating `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` without putting quotes around it or something. I'm new to writing bat files, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here's some deets about my system:

```
Windows 10 Pro 
V. 1607 
OS Build 14393.479
64-bit
Surface Book
```

Comment: could you explain how your question or the answer involves entering credentials automatically?

Comment: @barlop I haven't gotten that far yet, just wanted to include it in the off chance someone would include it in their answer. From my research I don't think it's possible, except perhaps by executing a javascript file once the page opens. I'll post in the comments if I figure it out.

Comment: i've heard of selenium.. another thing , maybe more appropriate, is an extension called iMacros

Comment: @barlop I was able to enter credentials with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/). However, it was a while ago so I don't know the actual script I used. iirc it wasn't as hard as I thought it was going to be. If I find it, I'll post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even If you are using the Environment var

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%
```

usually expands to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Paths having spaces in them have to be enclosed in quotes

Second is that Start uses the first argument in Quotes as title. See `Help Start`

This changed batch works as expected:

```
@echo off
cls
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --incognito "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier"
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from that post was using the user path rather than Program Files (x86). Therefore it makes the unfortunate assumption that there won't be a space in the path.

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe

Since "Program Files (x86)" has a space, you need to surround the path in quotes.

> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Since the expansion of {%Programfiles(x86)%} includes a space, you must have quotation marks around it. As a result, you must double the quotation marks you already have in the command line, resulting in a line looking like this:

```
start "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --incognito ""https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier"""
```

Note that it has been quite a while since I needed to do this, and the correct answer could be this one, where the command and the parameter are separately quoted:

```
start "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe --incognito" "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier"
```

One of these will work. I just can't remember which one right now.

Comment: That won't work. The first argument in quotes becomes the window title ...